# Routing two subnetworks through the same gateway

Tags: linux, routing

I have a routing problem I'm not quite sure why I'm not able to solve it. Perhaps I'm thinking about it in the wrong way.

On my company every client gets an IP through DHCP, but the admin does not want people to plug unkown computer into the network. Because I use many embedded system and notebooks, etc. that run linux and I don't want to go to the admin to tell him the newest MAC, he allowed my to run my own subnetwork on my notebook.

My `eth0` interface get an IP over DHCP

My `eth2` interface is configured to 192.168.10.1

I've installed and configured on my notebook isc-dhcp-server and bind. I span the 192.168.10.0/24 network and the dhcp-daemon listens only to incoming request through eth2.

```
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.10.100 192.168.10.200;
  option routers 192.168.10.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.1;
  allow bootp;
  authoritative;

  server-name "192.168.10.1";
  next-server 192.168.10.1;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
  option domain-name "intern.pse.de";

  ... (many host entries)
}
```

I also have a have this script that I execute whenever I need to start my `dhcpd` server:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth2 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This setup works fine, any system that get connected to my `eth2` gets some IP and is able to access the internet.

My company also has a wifi network and for test purposes I have a device (a siemens plc) that is available over the wifi. With wpa_supplicant I connected my `wlan0` interface to the wifi and assigned a fixed address:

```
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.99
```

I need that one of my embedded systems (with ip 192.168.10.113) have access to a siemens plc that is available over the wifi. My embedded is connected to my `eth2` interface and it can reach the internet without a porblem. So I thought that I should be able to ping the plc with the IP 192.168.1.160. On the embedded system I was not able to ping plc.

So I started looking in google for commong routing setups and I found this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/ specially the part *II. A Sample Network Architecture (to understand routing)* where there is a gateway and 2 different subnetworks. This resembles very much what I wanted to do, so I added this route (like in the linked article) to my notebook:

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.99
```

But this didn't work either. My embedded system still cannot ping the plc.

My whole routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.3     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     192.168.1.99    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.90.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 intern0
```

What am I missing? How can I setup my routes so that my 192.168.10.0/24 clients are able to access everything that is accessable through my `wlan0` interface?

Comment: it sounds like you want to change your default routing from going out eth0 to instead going out wlan0, yes?  In your script you have this line, `iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE` perhaps replacing `eth0` with `wlan0` and re-running this will achieve your goal?

Comment: if it won't work you might need to check with your sys admin that he's allowing this; he could be discarding the packets from private networks by default.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Now I'm at the office and take a good look at it again. @user16081-JoeT: no, I still want my notebook to route through `eth0`

Comment: huh, the answer you marked correct was exactly what i suggested

Comment: yes, you're right. I got confused with your answer because you said that it sounded like I wanted to change my default routing from eth0 to wlan0 and that was not the case. I used `iptables ... -j MASQUERADE` twice, once for `eth0` and once for `wlan0`. What does this line actually do?

Comment: thanks.  to get to the siemens plc that is available over the wifi, you cannot route through eth0.  you must go through wlan0.  As I understand this line, it lets your PC act as the router and perform NAT for the connected device, so that your PC's NIC "masquerades" as the device connecting to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your wireless devices don't know how to get to 192.168.10.0/24.  Try adding this as well, so they think the requests are coming from your PC's main network address:
    iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

Also I think you don't need the route for 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.99.  This should be covered by wlan0's your existing route.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, I'm going to try it